# Integrating int array into char array

Tags: c, arrays

I've created an int array which scanf values.
Now I want to take those values and use them to create a char array.
Meaning, the int value represent the number of cells to fill in the char array;
if intarray=3, 3 chararray index will be filled with '*' or 'void'.

For example, if intarray is `3 4 2 1` then
chararray will be `(void)(void)(void)****(void)(void)*`.

I am coding in C and cannot use strings.

Example run:

```
Enter picture size:  
10  
Enter 10 encoded lines:  
0 10 -1  
10 0 -1  
0 1 1 6 1 1 -1  
0 2 1 4 1 2 -1  
0 3 1 2 1 3 -1  
0 4 2 4 -1  
0 3 1 2 1 3 -1  
0 2 1 4 1 2 -1  
0 1 1 6 1 1 -1  
10 0 -1
```

Output:

```
+----------+
|          |
|**********|
| *      * |
|  *    *  |
|   *  *   
|
|    **    |
|   *  *   |
|  *    *  |
| *      * |
|**********|
+----------+
```

This picture contains 34 asterisks.

My code so far:

```
int main()
{
int a[10][10]={{0}};
char b[10][10]={{0}};
int line=0, columna=0, columnb=0, temp1=0, temp2=0, size, count=0;
    printf("Enter picture size:\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("Enter %d encoded lines:\n", size);
    for (line=0; line<size; line++){
        scanf(" %d", &temp1);
        while (temp1!=-1){
        a[line][columna]=temp1;
        columna++;
        scanf(" %d", &temp1);
        }
        columna=0;
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (line=0; line<size; line++){
        for (columna=0; columna<10; columna++){
        printf("%d ", a[line][columna]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    columna=0;
    for (line=0; line<size; line++){
        while (a[line][columna]!=-1){
            a[line][columna]=temp2;
            while (temp2!=0){
                if (columna%2==0){
                b[line][columnb]='*';
                columnb++;
                temp2-=1;
                }
                else{
                b[line][columnb]=' ';
                columnb++;
                temp2-=1;
                }
                columna++;
                a[line][columna]=temp2;
            }
        }
    }
    for (line=0; line<size; line++){
        for (columnb=0; columnb<size; columnb++){
        printf("%c", b[line][columnb]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
printf("This picture contains %d asterisks", count);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "created an int array which scanf values" and "cant use any functions" appears to be a contradiction.  Please clarify and add more examples.

Comment: What do you mean by filled with void ? If you mean `void` as the type, it can't be assigned to a `char`, if you mean "void" as a string of characters it cannot be assigned to it either.

Comment: By void I mean that the char array will be filed with '*' or not at all.
The idea is to creat a picter with '*' only (like griddlers)

Comment: what have you coded?

Comment: Posting your example here as text is preferred over posting text elsewhere as a picture.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry for that.
Its my first qustion asked here so Im stiil trying to add the code as a text

Comment: Please reopen my Q Ive added more info

Comment: what is the problem with your code?

Comment: 1. the program gets stuck whenever I enter array greater than 3X3  
2. I can't create the char array curectly - it doesnt work.

Comment: Your naming of variables make it extremely difficult to understand the code, I'd suggest using a little informational names, for example, I'd use line instead of ia, and maybe column instead of ja.

Comment: You've posted your code at the minute - good. But what does it currently do and what do you expect it to do? I can't see a specific question here. As it stands it just seems to be "My code doesn't work".

Comment: as for now, my code seems to get stuck right after the first printf (where I want it to print the intarray to see if it scanned correctly)  
as for the overall code Ive said that I want it to integrate the intarray into the chararray but I juct cant configure the chararray. My Q is how do I build that chararray

Comment: @NoamMeir Do you mean it stuck after `printf("Enter picture size:\n");` and before `scanf("%d", &size);`?

Answer (score 0):

> my code seems to get stuck

That's because in the first place the `while (a[line][columna]!=-1)` loop is endless, since neither `line` nor `columna` nor the condition that `a[0][0]` doesn't equal `-1` changes.

Consider this much simpler code to fill the `b` matrix:

```
    for (line=0; line<size; line++)
        for (columnb=columna=0; columna<10; columna++)
            // let's use your temp2 for the end position up to which to fill b
            for (temp2 = columnb+a[line][columna]; columnb < temp2; columnb++)
                b[line][columnb] = "* "[columna%2];
```